# ui-select close-on-select option is not working in ipad/iphone

Tags: ipad, ui-select

I am new to ui-select and using to show up multi select  options where I want dropdown to be open and it can be done by using close-on-select="false" option as shown below but it works in desktop all major browsers and android platform but it does not work on the ipad/iphone meaning when I click on any where else other than ui-select dropdown should close.

```html
 <ui-select close-on-select="false" multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Comment: here is the plunker sample for the ui-select http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview

Comment: Look into using punctuations in your sentences.